# How to display number as Hundred separator formator in oracle?

Tags: oracle, number-formatting

When I'm retrieving number column in oracle getting like this 1237.89
I want to display number column as 1,237.89

How to get this in Oracle.

Comment: Retrieving and displaying where? It it's through a client then that may have its own settings (including [column-specific formatting in SQL\*Plus etc.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#sthref555)); if its an application you're writing then you'll need to handle display yourself. Otherwise you can convert a number to a formatted string - as long as you don't then plan to treat it as a number, i.e. for display only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `to_char` with the optional format argument:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(mycol, '9,999.99')
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer D (for decimals) and G (for thousands' groups), e.g.

```
SQL> select to_char(123456789, '999G999G990D00') result from dual;

RESULT
---------------
 123.456.789,00

SQL>
```